# ANTLR : How to parse fixed length text file based on index position using ANTLR 4?

Tags: antlr4

**Input:**

```
101 04200001312345678981107291600A094101US FORD NA             TEST COMPANY101                
5225TEST COMPANY                       11234567898PPDTEST BUYS 110801110801   1098765430000001
```

Above lines are 94 char fixed length.

**Expected output:** Based on this input , Antlr grammar should parse based on index positions.

For Example: If parser identify '1' in starting char of line one. It should recognize entire line as a separate string as **HEADER1**.

Same as if parser finds '5' in starting index of line two. It should recognize entire line as a separate string as **HEADER2**.

Answer (score 1):

```
fragment Digit: '0'..'9' ;
fragment Alpha: '_' | 'A'..'Z';

Number: Digit+ ;
Alphanumeric: (Letter | Digit)+ ;

header1: '1' Alphanumeric+
header2: '5' Alphanumeric+

WS
  : (' ' | '\t') -> skip //channel (HIDDEN) 
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Which tool are you using for parsing?

I get the following tree while parsing with your grammar using Antlr v4 plugin in Android studio.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a  lot @vineeshvs. I am using Antlr's in build gui option to parse the grammar. I am also getting same result . But my requirement is the first char position should come in place of missing '1'. For example: In first line, 1 will be separate node remaining 93 char will be in separate node. To be clear if parse finds '1' in start position it should recognize as file header and read remaining 93 char. If i will get your contact details.. i will explain my requirement very clear. As I am new to antlr, i need someone's support to guide me like guru.