# How to write a grammar for parsing alphanumeric text using Antlr4?

Tags: antlr4

```
5200USCOMPANYNAME3490SUPPLEMENTAL0COME03062036121DNESUPPS0E123C  0908030908032152062036120000005
```

I have to split this line based on position using antlr4

0th position - name1
01-03rd postion - name2 
.
.
.
Nth position - nameN

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and be sure to ask [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to go through some Antlr tutorials first. ([Example](https://tomassetti.me/antlr-mega-tutorial/#setup-antlr))

Parsing alphanumeric characters in Antlr.

```
fragment Digit: '0'..'9' ;
fragment Alpha: '_' | 'A'..'Z';

Number: Digit+ ;
Alphanumeric: (Letter | Digit)+ ;
```

[Credits](https://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/antlr-interest/2007-October/024088.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot...Could you please look into my another question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53649431/antlr-how-to-parse-fixed-length-text-file-based-on-index-position-using-antlr